# Facebook video doesn't play inline

Tags: video, facebook

I uploaded a mp4 video on facebook and it doesn't play directly on the wall, but opens a separate window to play.

I see very often other videos that play inline, i.e. inside the wall.

What is the secret ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"According to Facebook, only videos posted by individual Facebook users or verified pages (such as celebrities) will play automatically within mobile. Videos will play silently until a user taps to hear sound. When the video stops playing, the user will be taken back to News Feed. Only videos uploaded directly to Facebook (or Instagram) will play automatically — not YouTube or Vimeo or other platform apps which post to Facebook."

Hopes this helps.

source http://www.insidefacebook.com/2013/09/12/facebook-to-test-autoplay-videos-in-mobile-news-feed/

Comment: echeola, thanks, but it doesn't matter mobile or not, autoplay or not, the question is - play inline (inside the wall) or open a separate window to play ?

Comment: I guess I was trying to establish that you are uploading directly to Facebook as an individual, not using a different service. If you are, are the videos previewing without sound? Then you click on then a new window opens and they play with sound?

Answer (score -1):

Years later, same situation. Refresh your page (while on desktop) and the player will work inline once again. It must be the way content is loaded by the underlying technology (React and Javascript) used to update what is rendered on a page.

I am just guessing but that would seem the most likely culprit since it involves updating the DOM (Document Object Model) which is how the browser is able to show content on web pages. If returning to a given page after a while, seems like the DOM has changed so significantly that instead of rendering the differences between the virtual DOM (kept by react) and the one on the actual page, the algorithm is no longer able to let videos playback within a post (inline) therefore it triggers the default post behavior which is to open them in a separate overlay where it will be re-rendered as newly fetched content.

Most likely not a priority for FB to fix this issue since content isn't broken but it's just shown in a different format (not inline) and although it affects negatively user experience and breaks UI consistency, it doesn't cause a loss of functionality as users will still be able to "consume" content and that's what's most important for FB's bottom line.